# Find first free element

Tags: c#, linq

I looking for query which return first number not available in list

```
int[] list = new int[] { 1,4,2,5,6,7 };
```

For above example I expect to have result 3.

Comment: BTW, that's an array, not a `List<int>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
int result = Enumerable.Range(1, list.Length)
                       .Where(i => !list.Contains(i))
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return `0` if `list` contains all integers from 1 to *n*.

Answer (score 1):

```
var first = Enumerable.Range(1, list.Max()).Except(list).First();
```

Comment: I'd use `list.Count()` rather than `list.Max` so you don't need to bother computing the max value.  Also you can use `First` instead of `Min` to allow for short circuiting, as the first value is always the smallest.